# MySQL - Aren't these privileges enough to create a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am connecting to mysql server via PHP with a user with the following grants:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password hash'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, CREATE ROUTINE ON `accountperfix\_dbname`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'
```

Yet, a simple `CREATE TABLE` query fails with the following error:

```
Could not create geoip table : CREATE command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' for table 'geoip'
```

Isn't the bear `CREATE` between `DELETE` and `DROP` enough to create tables? What grant is missing?

P.S. I don't have access to PHPMyAdmin or any other probing tools on this particular host.

Comment: Can't you just install PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: @ceejayoz - No, that is not an option.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but have you selected the correct database for issuing the `CREATE` statement?

Comment: and did you run the "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" command to get theses changes in the running instance?

Comment: @Majid - you are assign the right to database `accountperfix\\_dbname`, is it intended? **Or** is meant for `accountperfix_dbname`?

Comment: @goreSplatter - Yes. I'm using a php var which does not change between the connection creation and create table query.

Comment: @regilero - No I wasn't aware that might be necessary (don't know what it does actually). Talking of `instance`, are noting that I'm doing this with PHP? Does `instance` exist in this context too?

Comment: @ajreal - I am not assigning anything to the user. The snippets are not queries, but results. I explained this in a comment under TriggerTG's answer.

Comment: @regilero - I guess I understand what you mean now. You are assuming I am granting privileges to the user in the top snippet and immediately using those privileges to create the table, in which case as the current `instance` has a set of cached privileges not including the new ones will fail unless we force it to refresh the privileges info for that user. But as I said I am not altering the grants, I am just reading them. So that will not work *sigh*.

Comment: yes, when you run the grant queries, they're not taking in account until a flush privileges occurs or a database restart. Now your problems remains, certainly with "accountperfix\_dbname" if it's not the name of your database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider your ON-Statement:

```
ON `accountperfix\_dbname`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'
```

But you didn't mention the name of the respective database.

Comment: The db name is here represented by `dbname`, also, there is not any `ON statement` to reconsider; the code snippet is the result of a `SHOW GRANTS FOR '$user'@'$host'` query, not a query of its own.

Comment: Well, then reconsider the name of the databases you want to grant access to. Does the actual database name match that pattern?
This is an example from my database: <code>GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'hash'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `databasename`.* TO 'username'@'localhost'</code>